# Data transfer between iphone and BT device

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Is it possible to transfer data from/to iphone through headset using some modulation(fsk for example)? From theoretical point of view it looks completely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could consider in-code FSK demodulation.

Take a look at O'Reilly's [iPhone Hacks](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516642.do) - there's a nice chapter on serial modem.
True - it uses Headphone Jack but you'll get the feeling on how to handle audio 'data'.

You can also download the source from [iPhone Hacks source code](http://labs.perceptdev.com/iphone-hacks-source-code-2/)

EDIT: there's also an awesome link collection in not really Jake's answer here:

[Using an iPhone audio dongle to transmit data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341280/using-an-iphone-audio-dongle-to-transmit-data)