# Wired connection from iPhone to Raspberry Pi

Tags: ios, iphone, raspberry-pi

I would like to build an application on my iPhone that connects to my raspberry Pi. Because these are going to be in close proximity (next to each other), I'd like to use the wired connection (lightning port to USB) to communicate. Is this possible or must I use wireless technologies? My assumption is that wired would be better as it ensures a connection and would be faster, however, I am open to be corrected.

This is related to a hobbyist project where I want to access a raspberry pi sensor on my iphone. The sensor (and Pi) will be next to the iphone. I'm building a custom weird case to combine them.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Thanks
Iain

Comment: @Eimantas: OP is asking about wired connection. BLE devices also have very low troughput.

Comment: @rokjarc he's open to be corrected and asks if he must use wireless. So wireless is an option.

Comment: Ok. In that case - yes, without applying for MFi (it is not so complicated for a company but i don't know for hobbyist), BLE is one of your options. Troughput will be < 3kb/s. Another option would be hardware modem (FSK or similar) on the RPi side and a softare modem on the iOS side (communication via audio jack). In any case: USB or UART connection (MFi needed) would indeed be much faster.

Comment: And there is also WiFi option (no MFi needed). If you have more experience with electronics you might want to use a module like one MRF24W family, or maybe one of the WiFly modules...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For communication with peripheral devices (Raspberry Pi for example) you have several alternatives.

**UART via 30-pin or lightning connector** (MFi needed)

**USB via 30-pin or lightning connector** (MFi needed)

Quick start: [Microchip's development kits](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/smartphoneaccessory/tools/home.html). This module can prolong communication to RPi or you can try to implement the Accessory stack (and communication with authentification chip) to RPi itself.

**FSK or similar modulated-audio communication via audio-jack** (no MFi needed)

You would have to implement hardware FSK modem on the RPi side and a software one on the iOS side. It is a bit tricky but by no means impossible.

Of course you could implement software modem on the RPi side, too. But since RPi doesn't have audio input you would have to use an USB audio card or something. Or complicate your life trying to sample an analog pin fast enough.

User not really Jake made a quite impressive list of links on this topic [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259877/653513).

**Bluetooth as an External Accessory** (MFi needed)

Quick start: [RN-41/42-APL](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/RN-41_42-APL-PB_v1_2r.pdf)

Easy to use Bluetooth stack. Communication with authentification chip is handled by the BT module. Note that when communicating with iOS devices data troughput is not much better than when using BLE modules.

**Bluetooth as a** [BLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) **module** (no MFi needed)

Data troughput not much worse then *the old* BT. Implementing the communication might be a bit more tricky code-wise. [This module](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/rowdyrobot/arduino-ble-shield-connecting-the-ios-and-the-ardu/posts) seems interesting.

**WiFi communication** (no MFi needed)

WiFi might be a good choice. But for your device and iOS device to be able to find eachother you will need either static IP (for the server device) or minimal [Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) ([Bonjour](https://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/)) implementation.

When using WiFi you can go either with infrastructure network (using external Access Point) or you could go with AdHoc (created by your device). Later seems promising but be careful - iOS7 & AdHoc network don't seem to work well together yet.

With WiFi you have many modules to choose from. A simpler to use would be a module like [RN-XV WiFly Module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10822). TCP stack is already implemented in the module - you can use simple UART communication. I'm not sure how to implement Zeroconf on this one.

Or there are *raw* WiFi modules like [MRF24WG0MA/MB](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70686B.pdf). They are stable and reliable and they can be used on home-etched PCB. Downside for RPi user would be that you would almost certainly need an PIC24 or something between the RPi and MRF24W. Microchip provides free TCP/IP stack for their microcontrollers and this stack includes Zeroconf.

**And the easiest way**: you could simply use a WiFi dongle (with RPi) for communication. Zeroconf should be easy enough to implement on the RPi - and it's not even needed at the begining if you are ok with assigning static IP to the RPi (if it acts as a server).

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible without signing up for apples MFI program. You have to pay and sign a bunch of NDA's.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

You can use other methods, like bluetooth and connection over the audio port.

Comment: Looking at the MFI program you need to be a company to sign up. For my project I'll guess I'll have to use Bluetooth. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Here's a MFi compliant wired solution for Lightning to USB: redpark.com Serial+Power Cable L4-DB9PV (lightning to DB9 and it's MFi, $115) connected to Startech Port USB to Null Modem RS232 ICUSB232FTN ($20).  I'm researching this topic myself, so I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks, the link was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

While @RokJarc's answer is pretty complete, I've also had success with both wired (lightning to usb) and wireless connections using iOS's personal hotspot. Here are the steps:

For wired, on the Pi, install `ipheth-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils
```

And add an `eth1` network interface by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` to include:

```
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
```

For wireless, make sure `/etc/network/interfaces` has a wireless network entry such as:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

If you are using wpa_supplicant and add a network entry for the iPhone's hotspot in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
network={
    ssid="Banana Phone"
    psk="ring ring ring"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    id_str="banana"
    priority=3
}
```

The ssid should be the name of the phone from `Settings -> General -> About -> Name` and the password should come from the personal hotspot screen.

Now start the personal hotspot on your phone. The pi should automatically connect when connected by a usb to lighting cable or using wifi. After connecting, the pi should be assigned an ip somewhere in `172.20.10.x`. You can run `ifconfig` on the pi to figure out which one. (I believe that you should be able to define a static ip here but haven't messed around with that yet)

From there, you can connect another computer to the hotspot and ssh into the pi using the `172.20.10.x` ip or even ssh directly from the phone.

---

In my personal testing, latency over lightning is consistently low and I've [used this on both a Raspberry Pi Two and Raspberry Pi Zero for streaming realtime mjpeg video from two cameras to a VR headset](http://blog.mattbierner.com/tenome/). In this scheme, the network is a fairly small source of the 100ms or so latency. The experience is not Vive quality of course, but it is still usable and the iPhone + Pi combo provides lots of fun hacking opportunities

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with Mfi.You can run usbmuxd service on your Raspberry Pi. The usbmuxd will transfer the USB data into socket packets. Your iOS App also need to implement the same protocol to rx/tx the data from/to your Raspberry Pi.
David House has already made this work. https://github.com/davidahouse/PiTalk